# A double Summation involving 7th roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

Is there possibly a closed form for $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{6} \dfrac{1}{m-\alpha^k}\right)^2$$ where $\alpha=e^{2\pi i/7}$ ?

I'm having problems evaluating the first sum, let alone the second. I tried some algebraic manipulation, but I could only find that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{6} \dfrac{1}{1-\alpha^k}=3$ using the fact that $\dfrac{1}{1-\alpha^k}+\dfrac{1}{1-\alpha^{7-k}}=1$

Hints and answers appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The six numbers $m-\alpha^k$ are the roots of $f(X) = \frac{(m-X)^7 - 1}{m-X-1} = X^6 + a_5 X^5 + \cdots + a_1 X + a_0$, so the sum of their reciprocals is $-\frac{a_1}{a_0}$.

Letting $X=0$, we have $a_0 = \frac{m^7-1}{m-1}$.  Taking a derivative, we have $a_1 = -\frac{6m^7 -7m^6+1}{(m-1)^2}$, therefore:

$$s_m = \sum_{k=1}^6 \frac{1}{m-\alpha^6} = \frac{(6m^7 - 7m^6 + 1)}{(m-1)(m^7-1)} = \frac{6m^5 + 5m^4 + 4m^3 + 3m^2 + 2m + 1}{m^6 + m^5 + m^4 + m^3 + m^2 + m + 1}$$ $$= \frac{7m^6}{m^7-1} - \frac{1}{m-1}$$

(the last form comes from taking the logarithmic derivative, which ccorn suggested)

You can check that this gives $3$ for $m=1$.  You can also quickly verify that $s_m \leq 21/m$, so $\sum_{m=1}^\infty s_m^2$ converges, and is less than $\frac{147}{2}\pi^2$.  This is a very crude bound; after a few initial terms we should have $s_m \approx 6/m$, so the sum is closer to $6\pi^2$.

As for the possible existence of a closed form... well, good luck with that.

---

Addendum: I think this should not even be attempted until there is a solution for the same problem with *third* roots of unity, as this already seems quite hard, yet the corresponding problem for second roots of unity is quite tractable.  In other words, is there a closed form for the following sum?:

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left( \frac{2m+1}{m^2 + m + 1} \right)^2 = 1 + \sum_{m=2}^\infty \left( \frac{3m^2}{m^3-1} - \frac{1}{m-1} \right)^2$$

There *are* closed forms involving the logarithmic derivative of the gamma function... but I generally don't accept something as a closed form if it's both conceptually more difficult and harder to evaluate than the original formula.

---

Another observation:

$$\frac{(2m+1)^2}{(m^2 + m + 1)^2} = 4\cdot \frac{1}{m^2 + m + 1} - 3\cdot \frac{1}{(m^2 + m + 1)^2}$$

The second sum actually *does* have a closed form, though it's a doozy:

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m^2 + m + 1} = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}} \left( \coth(\pi \sqrt{3}) -\frac{1}{2}\coth(\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{2})  \right)$$

(this is derived from the identity $\coth x = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{\pi^2m^2 + x^2}$, which comes from Fourier something something)

What this means is that there is a closed form for $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(2m+1)^2}{(m^2 + m + 1)^2}$ if and only if there is a closed form for $\sum_{m=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{(m^2 + m + 1)^2}$.  This seems like a useful transformation, since the latter looks more standard and has probably been studied.

---

This seems to come down to finding a closed form for the real part of $\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m-\omega)^2}$, where $\omega$ is a third root of unity.  This looks promising, but there might still be a negative answer.

Comment: You seem to be missing a power on the term with coefficient $-3$ after "Another observation:".

Comment: @aschepler Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let us reorder our sum by summing over $m$ first, we have:

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{j=1}^6 \frac{1}{m-\alpha^j}\right)^2
= \sum_{j=1}^6 \left( \sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(m-\alpha^j)^2}\right)
+ \sum_{j=1}^6\sum_{k=1,\ne j}^6\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(m-\alpha^j)(m-\alpha^k)}\right)
$$
Recall the infinite product expansion of [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function),

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} = z e^{\gamma z} \prod_{m=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{z}{m}\right)e^{-\frac{z}{m}}$$

Taking logarithm and differentiate twice
and using the relation $\Gamma(z+1) = z\Gamma(z)$, we find:

$$-\psi(1+z) = \gamma + \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{m+z} - \frac{1}{m}\right)
\quad\implies\quad
\psi'(1+z) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m+z)^2}
\tag{*1}$$

where $\psi(z) = \frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). From this, we find

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m-\alpha^j)^2} 
&= \psi'(1-\alpha^j)\\
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m-\alpha^j)(m-\alpha^k)} 
&= 
\frac{1}{\alpha^j-\alpha^k}\sum_{m=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{m-\alpha^j} - \frac{1}{m-\alpha^k}\right)\\
&= - \frac{\psi(1-\alpha^j)-\psi(1-\alpha^k)}{\alpha^j-\alpha^k}
\end{align}
$$
and our sum is

$$\sum_{j=1}^6 \psi'(1-\alpha^j) - \sum_{j=1}^6\sum_{k=1,\ne j}^6\frac{\psi(1-\alpha^j)-\psi(1-\alpha^k)}{\alpha^j - \alpha^k}\\
\approx 28.3895279881439339857786846204067953172346...
$$